# Determine what running “make install” changes on most any Linux platform

Tags: linux, make

How can I determine what running `make install` runs or installs when I have no way of uninstalling from source code? I’d prefer a portable method or at least a software package that can be found in Ubuntu or openSUSE or really any popular Linux distribution.

Comment: `-n`, `--just-print`, `--dry-run`, `--recon` Print the commands that would be executed, but do not execute them. Will give some clues ...

Comment: @JakeGould That assumes an appropriate `test` target. I use `test` to run `junit` tests.

Comment: @DavidPostill The output is complete gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

> I’d prefer a portable method or at least a software package that can
>   be found in Ubuntu or openSUSE or really any popular Linux
>   distribution.

#### Using `find` to find all files created in the last hour.

While I consider this an “end run” idea, it’s a useful system administrator trick to just use `find` as `sudo` on `/` (root) to find any files created (`ctime`) in the last hour:

```
sudo find / -ctime -1
```

If you want slightly better details on those files just run the results through `ls -la` with `-exec` like this:

```
sudo find / -ctime -1 -exec ls -la {} \;
```

But of course, that reports on *all files created* and not just those generated by `make install`.

#### So a `make install` into a temporary directory and then create a directory tree of that directory for review.

There is this other cool technique from the user [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/645613/steve) on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15331397/117259); slightly tweaked for here:

```
mkdir /tmp/installer
./configure
make
sudo make install DESTDIR=/tmp/installer
cd /tmp/installer
tree .
```

The key of that is the `DESTDIR` setting which will—essentially—install all components into the `/tmp/installer`. The commands that follow just get you into that directory and then `tree` creates a nice directory tree of the contents of that directory.

And my two cents on that technique: Some systems like Mac OS X don’t have `tree` installed by this one liner combines `find` and `sed` to effect a similar type of directory tree formatting:

```
find . -print | sed -e 's;[^/]*/;|____;g;s;____|; |;g'
```

Comment: You don't know if a Makefile provides a `DESTDIR` parameter!